# Dialog - How to store MultichoiceItems with SharedPreferences and how to reuse it

Tags: java, android

Hello guys and good afternoon all.

I'm having some issues in finding a goood way to save in sharedPrefernces the selected items of my multichoiceDilog.

I've seen a bunch of codes here on the forum but anyone of them was useful for my scope.

Here is my dialog Code:

```
private ArrayList mSelectedItems;
private boolean[] itemsChecked = {false, false, false, false};
public void deleteDialog(){
    mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.deletefiles_title)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.options, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        mSelectedItems.add(which);
                    } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                        mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Save here the selected items
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

So mys question is, how can i store with a function the user choices?

And eventually how can i use the checked items in if statement?

I thought something like this:

```
    if(itemsChecked[1]){
     deleteDatabases();
}
```

What do you think guys? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple util class to handle my shared preferences:

```
public class SharedPreferencesUtil {

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    static {
        sharedPreferences = MBankApplication.appContext.getSharedPreferences(
                "sharedPreferenceKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public static void saveString(String key, String value) {
        editor.putString(key,value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void saveInt(String key, int value) {
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void saveLong(String key, long value) {
        editor.putLong(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void saveBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String loadString(String key, String defaultValue) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key,defaultValue);
    }

    public static int loadInt(String key, int defaultValue) {
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static long loadLong(String key, long defaultValue) {
        return sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static boolean loadBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static void removeString(String key) {
        editor.remove(key);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Let me know if you had any question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the problem is that i have to save and get values of a boolean Array and normally SharedPreferences doesn't support it so i must do some gimmick...